# Designing a MOSFET current mirror circuit

Tags: mosfet, integrated-circuit, design, fet, current-mirror

This is the design problem:

[image]

This is a brief of my design for W and L of the transistors and R:

[image]

I've connected the upper voltage source to ground and made the lower one equal to 0.4 V to make sure that N2 operates in the saturation region.

1. I don't know what to do with the condition (ro >= 5k ohm) in my design. Is it for simulator stage not for the design stage?
   ro is considered only for P2 and N2. Right?
2. Please give advices and notes on my design especially if there is something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

\$r_o>5\rm{k\Omega}\$ is the condition that sets the *length* of the transistors. It is desired for the PMOS current source and the NMOS current sink to have an output impedance \$r_o\geq 5\rm{k\Omega}\$. Knowing that \$I_D\$ is 50 or 100μA,
$$\frac{\Delta V_{DS}}{\Delta I_D} = r_o = \frac{1}{\lambda I_D}$$
Thus, for the PMOS,
$$\lambda = \frac{1}{r_oI_D}\leq \frac{1}{5\rm{k\Omega}\times50\rm{μA}}=4\rm{V^{-1}}$$
Likewise, for the NMOS, \$\lambda \leq 2\rm{V^{-1}}\$.

For a given device type, \$\lambda\$ is dependent only on \$L\$ and does not depend on \$W\$ or \$I_D\$. Therefore, this is the sequence of steps you should follow:

1. Determine what values for \$L\$ will give the desired \$\lambda\leq2\rm{V^{-1}}\$ for NMOS and \$\lambda\leq4\rm{V^{-1}}\$ for PMOS. Use the simulator to help. Generally, \$\lambda\$ scales inversely with \$L\$.
2. With the target value of \$V_{OV}=0.3\rm{V}\$, calculate the required \$W\$.
3. You already know that \$R=8\rm{k\Omega}\$.
4. You already know to scale the PMOS by \$2\times\$ and NMOS by \$4\times\$.

Answer (score 0):

Ro is the inverse of the slope of your Id vs. Vds curve.  You're right, it only really matters for P2 and N@.  Do you know the lambda (channel-length modulation) for your technology?  If you do, ro = 1 /( lamdba *Id ).  if you don't know lambda you can start with small L (minimum is a good place to start) and then increase L based on simulation results.  You will probably need L significantly larger than minimum.